# Colorbox won't display controls, border

Tags: jquery, controls, overlay, colorbox

I am trying to use Colorbox so that it will open upon load and alert visitors that registration has opened for a conference. I found the code I am using at [Javascript Coder](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-window.phtml).

I can't get the "X" to close Colorbox to display, nor will the surrounding black background appear. However, when you hover over where the X should be, you can tell that there should be something there. I am experiencing this problem in FireFox and IE.

I have a lot going on with this page - Flash, PrettyPhoto, Ajax - so I'm wondering if things are competing and if I should use a simpler method.

Any help you could give would be much appreciated. Here is a link to the test version: http://www.iais2012.org/test.htm

And please be kind - this is my first time building a website, never mind using all of this crazy code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use this popular library instead

http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Why the down vote? I would have been happy to get this answer before I knew of fancybox, would have saved me a lot of time...

Comment: This was actually very helpful. I ended up going with FancyBox - much simpler to use.

Answer (score 2):

Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iais2012.org/css/images/border.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iais2012.org/css/images/controls.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iais2012.org/css/images/loading_background.pngFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://www.iais2012.org/css/images/loading.gifFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```